# defining a table key with a variable

Tags: lua, lua-table

In PHP I can define a table/array like this:

```
$string = 'foo';

$array = array();
$array[$string] = 'bar';
print_r($array);         // Result: Array ( [foo] => bar )
```

so I used the `$string` to define the key of the first array entry.

How can I accomplish the same in lua?

Edit:

And can I access the result the like this?

```
print($array[$string]);  // Result: bar
```

Comment: Absolutely the same way: `arr = {}; str = 'foo'; arr[str] = 'bar'; print(arr.foo)`.  But there is no "first array entry": an array does not "remember" which key was added first and which key was added second. Keys are stored unordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
myArray = {}
someString = "foo"
myArray[someString] = "bar"
```

[Read more about tables in Lua here](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html).

Comment: You probably meant: myArray[someString] = "bar"